# com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket with spring boot and mongodb cloud

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Please suggest any solution for the below exception which is occuring while running my rest api while executing springboot application with mongodb cloud db. I have created collection in mongodb as well and configured below properties.

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:589) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:549) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:78) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

```
Model class
------------
package com.praveen.entity;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import lombok.Data;

@Document
public class Products {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private Integer p_id;
    private String p_name;
    private Integer p_cost;
    private Integer countInStock;
    private Integer numReviews;
    private String image;
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Integer getP_id() {
        return p_id;
    }
    public void setP_id(Integer p_id) {
        this.p_id = p_id;
    }
    public String getP_name() {
        return p_name;
    }
    public void setP_name(String p_name) {
        this.p_name = p_name;
    }
    public Integer getP_cost() {
        return p_cost;
    }
    public void setP_cost(Integer p_cost) {
        this.p_cost = p_cost;
    }
    public Integer getCountInStock() {
        return countInStock;
    }
    public void setCountInStock(Integer countInStock) {
        this.countInStock = countInStock;
    }
    public Integer getNumReviews() {
        return numReviews;
    }
    public void setNumReviews(Integer numReviews) {
        this.numReviews = numReviews;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Products [id=" + id + ", p_id=" + p_id + ", p_name=" + p_name + ", p_cost=" + p_cost + ", countInStock="
                + countInStock + ", numReviews=" + numReviews + ", image=" + image + "]";
    }
    
    
}
```

```
RestController class
---------------------

package com.praveen.rest;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.praveen.entity.Products;
import com.praveen.service.ProductsService;

@RestController
public class ProductsRestController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductsService service;
    
    @GetMapping("/products")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Products>> getProducts(){
        List<Products> allProducts = service.getAllProducts();
        if(allProducts != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Products>>(allProducts, HttpStatus.OK);
        }else {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Products>>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

```
Service class
--------------
package com.praveen.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.praveen.entity.Products;
import com.praveen.repository.ProductsRepository;

@Service
public class ProductsServiceImpl implements ProductsService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductsRepository prodRepo;
    
    @Override
    public List<Products> getAllProducts() {
        List<Products> productsList = prodRepo.findAll();
        if(productsList != null) {
            System.out.println(productsList);
            return productsList;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

```
Repository 
-----------
package com.praveen.repository;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.praveen.entity.Products;

@Repository
public interface ProductsRepository extends MongoRepository<Products, Serializable> {

}
```

```
application.properties
-----------------------
spring.data.mongodb.url = mongodb+srv://praveen:praveen@cluster0.qrvkm.mongodb.net/miniproject?retryWrites=true&w=majority
spring.data.mongodb.database = products
spring.data.mongodb.port = 27017
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true
```

```
pom.xml
-------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.praveen</groupId>
    <artifactId>NgRx-Products</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>05-MiniProject-NgRx-Products</name>
    <description>NgRx package with Products data using springboot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please suggest any solution for the above exception, I have given all my files in the above.

Comment: ConnectException: Connection refused is a network issue meaning that your app cant connect to your mongo host port. You could maybe first try with a local mongo server. Or else try to troubleshoot your network (using telnet, checking your firewall/proxy, etc), or maybe try first using mongo client.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue after moving the application to a new server (Linux). I am using IntelliJ IDEA and using 'create datasource' it successfully connects to the external MongoDB server. It worked fine on the other host.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding  this annotation to your main class file
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class})

Comment: Is this approach safe?

Answer (score 0):

Search services in start.
open it.
search for mongodb there.
start/restart mongodb services from there.
It should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

this exception occurs due to mongodb incorrect port in application properties. So only changing spring.data.mongodb.port=27017 in application.properties file made it work. Also make sure you started mongodb server locally.

Answer (score 0):

Check the connect to `MongoDB` sever locally with `url:portNumber` mentioned in the `application.properties` from where your code is getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot 3 and Kotlin:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration

@SpringBootApplication(
    exclude = [MongoAutoConfiguration::class],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in some simple steps:

- search for services in start menu.
- search mongo DB server and click on it.
- click on start/restart.
  Now try connecting in mongo DB, it works properly now.